# why we need to upcast or downcast any object in java? Tell me the real time use with example

Tags: java

I need to understand the reason behind upcasting and downcasting an object,
i know how to do it but still im confused why we need to do it, can you tell
me the real time use.

i know the basic of upcasting and downcasting but coudnt understand the reason.

Comment: Because Java is strongly typed and not duck-typed.

Comment: Partial duplicate, this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013215/upcasting-and-downcasting-in-java

Answer (score 0):

For a practical example, consider the class `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`. It implements `java.io.InputStream` and has some additional methods, such as `toByteArray()`, which returns an array of bytes.

So if you have an output stream

```
OutputStream os = ...
```

And **you're sure it's a ByteArrayOutputStream**, you can cast it and use the methods specific to the class as follows.

```
byte[] bytes = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toByteArray();
```

Comment: Can you say me any example in where real time object Upcasting is used and why there is need to use it?